# How can I offer a gzipped xml file for download using PHP

Tags: php, xml, gzip

I have a PHP script that creates an xml file from the db.  I would like to have the script create the xml data and immediately make a .gzip file available for download.  Can you please give me some ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can easily apply gzip compression with the [gzencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) function.

```
<?
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourFile.xml.gz");
header("Content-type: application/x-gzip");

echo gzencode($xmlToCompress);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: application/x-gzip');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.gz"');
 $data = implode("", file('somefile.xml'));
 print( gzencode($data, 9) ); //9 is the level of compression
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the [gzip module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) available,

```
<?php

  system('gzip filename.xml');

?>
```